# WIth doobie, how do I map Scala case class to postgresql column with type tstzmultirange?

Tags: postgresql, scala, mapping, doobie

So e.g. I create the table `vacations` in postgres:

```sql
create table if not exists vacations (
  person text primary key,
  vacations tstzmultirange not null
)
```

And on the Scala side, I have:

```
case class Interval(start: Instant, end: Instant)
case class PersonalLeaves(person: String, onLeave: Seq[Interval])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) has a **Data Type** named [Range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

> Range types are data types representing a range of values of some
> element type (called the range's subtype). For instance, ranges of
> timestamp might be used to represent the ranges of time that a meeting
> room is reserved. In this case the data type is tsrange (short for
> “timestamp range”), and timestamp is the subtype. The subtype must
> have a total order so that it is well-defined whether element values
> are within, before, or after a range of values.

and one of the built-in **range types** is

> `tstzrange` — Range of timestamp with time zone, `tstzmultirange` — corresponding Multirange

---

[Doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/index.html) has an [extension for PostgreSQL](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/15-Extensions-PostgreSQL.html) that offer support for

- [Java 8 Time Types (JSR310)](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/15-Extensions-PostgreSQL.html#java-8-time-types-jsr310-)
- [Array Types](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/15-Extensions-PostgreSQL.html#array-types)
- [Geometric Types](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/15-Extensions-PostgreSQL.html#array-types)
- [PostGIS Types](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/15-Extensions-PostgreSQL.html#array-types)
- [Other Nonstandard Types](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/15-Extensions-PostgreSQL.html#array-types) such as `uuid`, `inet` and `hstore`

There is an open issue to [add support for Range type](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/936) that was open on `Jul 4, 2019` and the last activity was on `Jul 29, 2019`.

If you look at the unit test of [postgres module](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/tree/v1.0.0-RC2/modules/postgres) for [postgres types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) named [TypeSuite](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/blob/v1.0.0-RC2/modules/postgres/src/test/scala/doobie/postgres/TypesSuite.scala#L245), you will see the following lines where all range types are not being checked:

```scala
  // 8.17 Range Types
  skip("int4range")
  skip("int8range")
  skip("numrange")
  skip("tsrange")
  skip("tstzrange")
  skip("daterange")
  skip("custom")
```

---

In this case, I think you will need to use the [Custom Mappings](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/12-Custom-Mappings.html) that doobie has. I was able to find a `gist` that creates a [custom mapping for tsrange](https://gist.github.com/ShahOdin/e1a87ccf67dafd378a9cbe1a7fbfc30f) which is pretty close to what you need. Also in the open issue mentioned before, there is [a suggestion about how custom mapping for ranges can be done](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/936#issuecomment-510859470).